# JavaScript print with POS printer paper size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to print specific div in POS printer. My printer name is **Optimuz** . I also tried with

```
<div id="printAreaInvoice" style="visibility: hidden;font-size:8px;width:200px;"></div>
                        
<input type='button' id='printInvoice' value='Print'>

 $(document).on('click','#printInvoice',function () {
            printJS({
                maxWidth: 440, // the width of your paper
                printable: 'printAreaInvoice', // the id
                type: 'html',
                css: 'print.css' // your css
            });
        });
```

**I loaded print content after page loaded. $('#printAreaInvoice').html(response.printData);**

contents loads on div like

```
echo '<table class="tblData" style="width:100%;font-size:8px;">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td style="font-size:8px;">'.$item_name.' ---- '.$per_item_price.' </td>';

echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

But it takes full width. Still I did not connect printer because of **availability**. How can I fix that . Is it possible on that printer. Thanks in advance

Comment: The best thing to do is use CSS to only show what you want.  And, you can use paper dimensions like inches, millimeters, etc.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I also use **style="width: 50px;"** for testing purpose. But It takes full paper width when it's pop up for print option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time I tried to use this library to print to POS printer. You can check the library here [PrintJS Library](https://printjs.crabbly.com/)

When you use this library you can do something like this

```
<div id="print">
    <h1>My Heading</h1>
    <p>My Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

And to print this one you can use something JS like this

```
printJS({ 
          maxWidth: 375, // the width of your paper
          printable: 'print', // the id
          type: 'html',
          css: 'print.css' // your css
});
```

In your print.css you will have something like this

```
@media print {
  #print h1 {
    font-size: 18pt;
  }
  #print p {
    font-size: 12pt;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I also configured with this library . I am informing u shortly to connect with printer. I would like to notify that. I set **maxWidth: 375** . But in pop up it shows full screen. Will it ok on printing ?

Comment: Depends on your paper. You can just try adjusting the value and print it.

Comment: I am trying to set font size but can't . Please help

Comment: For font you need to set inside your css and use media query "@media print" and set your style for any element there. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks to give me your valuable time. in **@media print** , here is **print** div id ? my print div is **<div id="printAreaInvoice"></div>** . So is it **@media printAreaInvoice** ?

Comment: I edited my answer, you can see how to use @media print. You can find more about media queries in this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: I made @media print {
    #print table{
       font-size: 10pt; 
    }
   
}    but it's not working

Comment: @Mithun can you put the html that you want to print. if you want to print the value inside the table you need to put style for the cell which is table tr td {font-size: 10pt;}

Comment: I also tested with **<td style="font-size:8px;">**

Comment: can you edit your question with your html please. Thanks